# MySQL - How can I compare if the order of a query result is the same of the another one?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Imagine I have a database table called **Log** and it seems like this:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | item_id | message |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  |    1    |    A    |
+----+---------+---------+
| 2  |    1    |    B    |
+----+---------+---------+
| 3  |    1    |    C    |
+----+---------+---------+
| 4  |    2    |    A    |
+----+---------+---------+
| 5  |    2    |    C    |
+----+---------+---------+
| 6  |    2    |    B    |
+----+---------+---------+
| 7  |    3    |    B    |
+----+---------+---------+
| 8  |    3    |    A    |
+----+---------+---------+
| 9  |    3    |    C    |
+----+---------+---------+
```

If I query

```
select * from log where item_id = 1 order by id;
```

I will receive the rows 1, 2 and 3. The same that if I query

```
select * from log where item_id = 1 order by message;
```

But if I make the same with item 2, orders will be different. Ordering by id, the order of rows will be 4, 5 and 6 but ordering by message will be 4, 6 and 5.

So here is my question, is it possible to make a query to know which `item_ids` have different orders comparing the two queries?

In this example the result would be items 2 and 3.

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: How do you know which is the previous query to compare with? Would the logic be something like _select for `item_id` = 2 and compare to `item_id` = 1_?

Comment: The version is 5.6.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `group_concat()`:

```
select l.item_id,
       group_concat(l.id order by l.id) as id_ordering,
       group_concat(l.id order by l.message) as message_ordering
from log l
group by l.item_id;
```

You can get the ones that are different using a `having` clause:

```
select l.item_id,
       group_concat(l.id order by l.id) as id_ordering,
       group_concat(l.id order by l.message) as message_ordering
from log l
group by l.item_id
having id_ordering <> message_ordering;
```

Comment: This is easy understanding, clear and effective. Simply perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables in order to solve this as a *gaps and islands* problem.

The following query:

```
SELECT id, item_id, message, id - seq
FROM (
  SELECT id, item_id, message,
         @seq := IF(@i = item_id, @seq + 1, 
                    IF(@i := item_id, 1, 1)) AS seq       
  FROM log
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 0, @seq := 0) AS v
  ORDER BY item_id, message) AS t
ORDER BY id;
```

generates this output:

```
id, item_id, message, id - seq
--------------------------------
1,  1,       A,       0
2,  1,       B,       0
3,  1,       C,       0
4,  2,       A,       3
5,  2,       C,       2
6,  2,       B,       4
7,  3,       B,       5
8,  3,       A,       7
9,  3,       C,       6
```

So `id-seq` can be used in order to detect order mismatches between `id` and `message`:

```
SELECT item_id
FROM (
  SELECT id, item_id, message,
         @seq := IF(@i = item_id, @seq + 1, 
                    IF(@i := item_id, 1, 1)) AS seq       
  FROM log
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 0, @seq := 0) AS v
  ORDER BY item_id, message) AS t
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id-seq) > 1  
ORDER BY id;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92c82/1)

Comment: This almost works but it gives false positives. If you add this values `(3453, 4, 'A'), (3454, 4, 'B'), (3455, 4, 'C'), (3456, 4, 'D'), (3457, 4, 'E'), (3600, 4, 'F')`, item 4 is also in the result and it shouldn't.

Comment: @JuanLopez Yes, I see your point. This can be easily fixed though if you add one additional variable that enumerates rows according to `id` in ascending order.

Comment: I can't see it. Would you mind editing your answer adding this point?